# Tracking the user function that threw the exception

Tags: c#, exception

I've been given a large application with only one `try..catch` at the outer most level.  This application also throws exceptions **all the time**, and is poorly documented.

Is there any pattern I can implement that will tell me what user method is being called, the exception being thrown, and also the count of exceptions?

I'm thinking of using a dictionary with reflection to get the needed information, but I'm not sure if this will work.  What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Exception.StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace.aspx) will give you the information you want (more so in a debug build).

If you can run in the Visual Studio debugger, turn on "break on exception" and you'll drop into the debugger at the "throw" site.

Answer (score 0):

[`Exception.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.tostring.aspx) should give you the stack trace and all required information. Use this to log the exceptions and you will be able to find the sources.

This is so long as there are indeed no other `try...catch` blocks in the application.